# Real function of one variable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

> *A real function of one variable is a set $f$ of ordered pairs of real numbers such that for every real number $'a'$ one of the following two things happen:*
>   (i) There is exactly one real number $b$ for which the ordered pair $(a, b)$ is a member of $f$. In this case $f(a)$ is defined and we write $f(a) = b$ the number $b$ is called the value of $f$ at $a$. 
>   (ii) $f(a)$ is undefined if there is no real number $b$ for which the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is a member of $f$.

If this is the ordered pair $(4, 2)$ $f(4) = 2$, where a = 4 and b = 2. If the value of $b$ becomes 5, then $f(4) ≠ 5$. Is it what the above quoted passage saying?

Comment: And we usually call your inittial $f$ the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ in this case is the set of all points $(x, f(x))$, for $x \in$ the domain on which $f$ is defined. $\quad x\overset{f}{\mapsto } f(x)$

If $x \in X$, $X$ being the domain of $f$, then $f(x)$ maps each $x \in X$ to a real value; the collection of all ordered pairs: $(x, f(x))$ to which $f$ maps $x$ can be considered a set in its own right.

With respect to your added example. If $(4, 2) \in f$, then we would cease to have a function if $(4, 5) \in f$. That is, $f$ would map $4$ to two distinct values.

If there exists no $b = f(a)$, for a given $a$, then the function is not defined at $x = a$: that is, $f(a)$ is undefined.

Comment: I've edited my question, please re-read it.

Comment: I tried to clarify, given your added question. Does this help, Samama?

Comment: What I don't understand in the above quoted passage is that why would there be exactly one real number $b$ for $a$ such that $f(a) = b$. How can we assign any value $b$ for $a$? For example in the square function, for every value of $a$ we get the squared value of $a$ but in _real function of one variable_ how do we know the real number $b$?

Comment: In the function $f(x) = x^2$, $f(a) = a^2 = b$ So for every real $a$ there is a real $b = a^2$. So the set of points defined by the function are all points of the form $(a, b) = (a, a^2)$. For each x = a, there is only one $f(a) = b = a^2$.

Comment: If we take the example of square function, and we have this ordered pair: (2, 3), then this ordered pair isn't a member of $f$?

Comment: Correct, Samama!

Comment: In which case, a function f(x) can be undefined. I mean there is always a real number 'b' for a real number 'x' if we are talking about square function?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you realized that the so-called set $f$ is the graph of your function. Let me recall some key facts about such graphs.

Let $G$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then **$G$ is the graph of a function** if and only if, for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the vertical line $\{(x,y)\;;\; x=a\}$ has at most one intersection point with $G$. Some people call this **the vertical line test**.

Let $G$ be such a set. Then we define the corresponding function $f$ as follows. The domain of $f$ is the set of all $a$ for which $G\cap\{x=a\}\neq\emptyset$. For such an $a$, the intersection is a single point $(a,b)$ and we set $f(a):=b$.

Conversely, check that if $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function, then
$$
G:=\{(a,f(a))\;;\;a\in D\}
$$
actually defines a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has the property stated above. This proves the characterization I started with.

**To answer your question:** if $(4,2)$ is on the graph of $f$, this means $f(4)=2$. If it is $(4,5)$, then $f(4)=5$. But both can't happen simultaneously, as a function takes only one value at a given point of its domain. That is the intersection characterization with vertical lines I started with.

Comment: @Samama Fahim Are you familiar with the concept of graph for a function?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with it.

Comment: @SamamaFahim Then this should not be that complicated. What you quote call $f$ the graph of $f$, actually, and that's misleading. On a vertical line, say $\{x=4\}$, there is at most one point which belongs to the graph of $f$. If it is $(4,2)$, this means $f(4)=2$. If it is $(4,5)$, this means $f(4)=5$. It there is none, this means $f(4)$ is not defined.